# Which one is best for hybrid mobile application development ? mowbly or phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Can any one suggest me the best hybrid mobile application development ? is it mowbly or phonegap ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am using phone gap and its great. I never used mowbly.

Answer (score 0):

Icenium is better(for me) you can check it out they have 30 days trial. http://www.icenium.com/